# move cards between lists using Trello API (python)

Tags: python, trello

I wanna move a card from List A to List B using Trello API.
I guess one way is to just copy a card and paste it in List B then delete the card from List A.
Is there any straightforward way to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 0):

just use PUT method and add idList query! url = "https://api.trello.com/1/cards/{id}"